# Azure DevOps Pipelines: Skip resolving deltas + tags in Checkout

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps for any pipeline it takes around a minute to checkout the code.  I have configured the fetch depth to 1 to speed it up but this doesn't have any effect on the time.  It spends around 10-15 seconds *Receiving objects* but after it has finished downloading the code it then goes through a process of *Resolving deltas* and listing tags *[new tag]* which came when we migrated the history from TFS to git.

Sample lines from log:

```
Receiving objects: 100% (139543/139543), 391.48 MiB | 19.37 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/91447)
[new tag]       TFS_C10006 -> TFS_C10006
```

Pipeline snippet:

```
stages:  
- stage: Build  
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 1
      clean: true
```

Do you know any settings which can be turned on at the pipeline to ignore tags and skip the deltas?  It takes the same amount of time on every Pipeline execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new option in Azure Devops to not sync tags when fetching a Git repository.

To opt-out from syncing the tags through YAML file, add the **fetchTags: false** to the checkout step. When the fetchTags option is not specified, it's the same as if fetchTags: true is used.

If you want to change the behavior of existing YAML pipelines, it may be more convenient to set this option in the UI instead of updating the YAML file. To navigate to the UI, open the YAML editor for the pipeline, select Triggers, then Process, and then the Checkout step.

If you specify this setting both in the YAML file and in the UI, then the value specified in the UI takes precedence.

Also, make sure you have **Shallow Fetch** enabled (it's enabled by default in Azure DevOps). For example: **fetchDepth: 1**

Test and confirm you are getting better results.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml#do-not-sync-tags-when-fetching-a-git-repository

Comment: At least with me this feature is not yet working.
But you can edit the pipeline -> go to the triggers -> in there go to the git settings and then disable  the fetching of tags. 
Not so nice because you configure something outside of the pipeline-yaml, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE Sep 2022: See the above answer - MS added an option to not sync the tags :)**

You can't configure to not download the `tags`.

The only way is to set `clean: false` to speed up the `checkout`, or disable the `checkout` and implement your git clone in the yaml.

See [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipelines-checkout-fetches-all-tags/1095986) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/git-source-provider-add-ability-to-pull-git-repos/878730).

You can check the agent git checkout code here:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/2224fd66cbf202835846523ee789b18a5f1e6355/src/Agent.Worker/Build/GitCommandManager.cs